# PHP: issuing a cron job once every 24hrs from initial date

Tags: php, cron

I was wondering if I could get some help.

I have a cronjob that is run every 5 mins.

I also have a number of entries in my DB with a 'start date' formatted like

```
 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'
```

What I want to do is run a specific command for each entry 24 hrs after the start date.

So for instance, if an entry has a start date of `2016-11-18 12:08:44`, I want to run a command on that entry at `2016-11-19 12:08:44 ...` Because the cron only runs every 5 mins, I don't expect to be exactly spot on 24hrs, but as close (5 mins each way) as possible.

Is there any chance someone could give me an example of how I could achieve this in PHP?

Much appreciated.

Comment: pure PHP or with a framework ?

Comment: So test the start date is 24hrs or greater OLDER than NOW AND that you have not already run the `whatever code`

Comment: @MathieuDormeval Pure PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the job like this :

1. Add a column "desired launch date" in the DB (Nullable).
2. Write a php script what calculate all 'desired launch date' from 'start_date' (and update the DB with calculed date).
3. Add block on this PHP script that initialize current datetime and compare with 'desired launch date' with an interval of 10 minutes.

**EDIT :**

Here a piece of source code, **not tested** !

```
$datetime = new \Datetime();
$timestamp = $datetime->getTimestamp();

$datetime_desired_launch = new \Datetime($your_formatted_datetime_from_db);
$desired_timestamp = $datetime_desired_launch->getTimestamp();

// I have manipulate timestamp for more efficiency
$launch_min_interval = $desired_timestamp - 5 * 3600; // - 5 minutes
$launch_max_interval = $desired_timestamp + 5 * 3600; // + 5 minutes

if ($timestamp >= $launch_min_interval && $timestamp <= $launch_max_interval) {
  // Here launch action...
}
```

Be careful of timezones !

Hope this help !

Comment: Is there any chance you could give me a code example for step 3 of your example please?

Comment: I have updated my post with small piece of code, please check.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use crontab to lance a script each 5 min

In this script you can check for date and lance the others scripts